# Single SPA + Vite - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: vue.js, rollup, vite, single-spa

I am using Typescript + Vite + Single SPA
Just trying to replicate the https://github.com/joeldenning/vite-single-spa-example
and https://github.com/joeldenning/vite-single-spa-root-config.

Hence, in my index.ejs I have

```
  <script type="systemjs-importmap">
{
  "imports": {
   "@org/root-config": "//localhost:9000/org-root-config.js",
    "@my/module": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/index.d4261135.js"
  }
}
```

and in org-root-config.js I have

```
import { registerApplication, start } from "single-spa";

registerApplication({
  name: "@my/module",
  app: () => System.import("@my/module"),

  activeWhen: "/",
});

start({
  urlRerouteOnly: true,
});
```

Regarding the MF itself, I have the following Vite config:

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  rollupOptions: {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    format: 'system',
    preserveEntrySignatures: true,
  },
  base: 'http://localhost:3000',
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          base: '/src',
        },
      },
    }),
    nodeResolve(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: '@',
        replacement: '/src',
      },
    ],
  },

};
```

The name of the MF module in package.json is "@my/module".

My main.ts is this:

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import Equal from 'equal-vue';
import { Quasar } from 'quasar';
import '@/axiosConfig';
import { setPublicPath } from 'systemjs-webpack-interop';
import singleSpaVue from 'single-spa-vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { store, vuexKey } from '@/store';
import { setupI18n } from './i18n';
import router from './router';
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css';
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass';

setPublicPath('@my/module');

const vueLifecycles = singleSpaVue({
  createApp,
  appOptions: {
    render() {
      h(App, {
        name: this.name,
      });
    },
  },
  handleInstance(instance: any): void | Promise<void> {
    instance.use(setupI18n())
      .use(store, vuexKey)
      .use(router)
      .use(Quasar)
      .use(Equal);
  },
});

export const bootstrap = vueLifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = vueLifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = vueLifecycles.unmount;
```

But the code it generates contains "import" and therefore, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" is shown. Can anyone help me with this?

The broswer complains about this part `{a as u,o as G,s as $,d as g,c as q,u as B,b as V,e as F,n as O,f as K,g as W,h as z,r as J,i as Q,w as P,j as m,k as X,l as Y,m as T,p as f,q as Z,t as ee,v as te,x as ne,y as oe,z as se,A as re,B as ae,Q as ie,C as ce}from"./vendor.ba4ac50a.js"`

Comment: Not related to the problem, but just a heads up - `export const bootstrap = vueLifecycles.bootstrap`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, just fixed this, although it didn't fix the issue

Comment: have you tried replacing `() => System.import("@my/module")` with `() => import("@my/module")` when registering your application

Comment: Why are you including the systemjs-webpack-interop? It sets the [__webpack_public_path__](https://github.com/joeldenning/systemjs-webpack-interop/blob/main/public-path.js#L42) which should not be used here.

Also, the alias might need a trailing / to not conflict with the `@` in your imports.

You could try this, which wouldn't match `@my/module` and others:

`{ find: '@/', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src') },`

Can you post a reproduction somewhere?

Comment: Have you seen this part of single-spa documentation https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-vite/#native-modules-vs-systemjs ? " a general recommendation is to use native modules during local development, but SystemJS in production (since browser support for Import Maps is still pending)." Looks like SystemJS solution is "still pending"

Comment: Are you running the MFE using `npm run dev`?  If yes, you cannot.  This is because Vite doesn't bundle while in DEV mode, and your code is using SystemJS.  If you go this route, you must always develop by bundling with `npm run build` and then previewing with `npm run preview`.  The alternative would be to move to native ES modules (drop SystemJS modules) from everywhere and use my plug-in `vite-plugin-single-spa`.